# Failing to connect to MongoDB on 27017 in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have updated NodeJs to V 0.12.7 and now when i try to start express server it gets started but its not getting connect to mongodb. Here's the stack trace.

```
F:\Node Restful API with Express4\server
> nodemon
12 Sep 10:50:51 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
12 Sep 10:50:51 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
12 Sep 10:50:51 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
12 Sep 10:50:51 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Magic happens on port 4040
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (F:\Node Restful API with Express4\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:78) 
at emit (events.js:118:17)
   at null.<anonymous> (F:\Node Restful API with Express4\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:19)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\Node Restful API with Express4\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at net.js:950:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
12 Sep 10:50:52 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Have you started MongoDB Process?

Comment: Yes i have started MongoDB process first.

Comment: can you check in other cmd window by entering mongo command and you can access mongo database.

Comment: when you dont have /data/db directory in your root path of mongodb process, then it stops. So..

Comment: create a directory and give its path while starting the mongodb server like
`mongod --dbpath "D:\data"`

Comment: Thanks @Rudra it was just `dbPath` that have been set to default, that was breaking the connection. It was set to default path which was in system drive and there were permission issues and i have moved directory to another drive and problem is solved now. Thank you everyone. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Windows** the `localhost` will not be available if the computer is not connected to the internet. Hence we need to write `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` to connect to MongoDB.